# Application Loader gives error: Not a valid zip file

Tags: ios, zip, ipa, application-loader

I'm trying to submit an app (.ipa) and the only error Application Loader gives is "Not a valid zip file."  It doesn't say anything about signatures, provisioning profiles, certificates, or binaries, etc.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're emailing the .ipa to your client, make sure it isn't getting munged either by their email software/server or by yours.  You may want to zip the .ipa (even though the ipa is already an archive format) in order to get the file to them without it being modified.  Then they can unzip it and submit the ipa file.  My guess is that the .ipa file suffix isn't being recognized by someone's mail software and that's damaging it somehow.

Comment: They're downloading it from our server, but we've come to the same conclusion: it's probably getting corrupted. Thanks!

Comment: Is it an FTP server? Those are pretty "helpful" in trying to translate documents line endings for you.  If an FTP server thought that an .ipa was a text file then it probably would corrupt it.

Answer (score 0):

If your zip file name has a space in it, e.g. `My App.zip`, try renaming the zip file so that it has no spaces, and try to upload it again. I seem to recall this happening to me once, and this did the trick.

Comment: But it's NOT a zip file... should it be? And there are already no spaces in the name.

Comment: If you're using Application Loader, then yes, it expects a zip file. What are you feeding it, if not a zip file, and it's complaining?

Comment: Um... so why are you not using Xcode to do the upload? Since Xcode4 came out, I have not used, nor needed to use Application Loader. With Xcode, you build an Archive, then in the Organizer window (in the Archive section) you can validate and then submit your app archive to Apple.

Comment: Because although I said *I* in the statement, we actually hand off the file to our client to submit. So *they're* the ones having trouble with it and they don't have the code, just the .ipa. But if it's a codesign error or something like that, then *I* have to fix it. I'm trying to make sure I did everything right on my end.

Comment: If it was a code signing error, I think the error would in fact say something to that effect. You could, as an alternative, create a zip file from the .app package you built, and have them try submitting that. (Don't zip the .ipa. Rather, find the .app package, right-click and choose "Compress <appname>.app".)